# framework 7 swipebox not able to display append images in cordova android app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, html-framework-7

`<img src="img/banner2.png" alt="image" class="col-100">`

1.above code display image in row. works fine when used static link as well as append html  using Jquery.

```
<a href="img/banner2.png" rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"></a>
```

2.when click on image, (image slider start) image enlarge and able to swap left and right to see other images.
for static code slider works fine but for append code image not enlarge and slider also not working some times.

HTML code below

```
      <div class="gallery row" > 
      <div id="gallery1" class="gallery row no-gutter "> 
              <a href="http://192.168.0.104/upload/gallery/3.jpg-22-2017-07-24-15-04:36:15pm.jpg" rel="gallery-1" class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="http://192.168.0.104/catking/upload/gallery/3.jpg-22-2017-07-24-15-04:36:15pm.jpg" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>

              <a href="img/banner2.png" rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="img/banner2.png" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a> 

              <a href="img/banner3.png"  rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="img/banner3.png" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>

              <a href="img/banner4.png"  rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="img/banner4.png" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>

              <a href="img/banner2.png"  rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="img/banner2.png" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>

              <a href="img/banner1.png"  rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="img/banner1.png" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>

              <a href="img/banner2.png"  rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="img/banner2.png" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>

              <a href="img/banner3.png"  rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="img/banner3.png" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>

              <a href="img/banner4.png"  rel="gallery-1"  class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="img/banner4.png" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript append code

```
myApp.onPageInit('gallery', function (page) {


    var gallery = "infrastructure";
    var url="http://192.168.0.104/app/processApp.php?callback=?";

    var dataString="gallery="+gallery+"&fetchGallery=";

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            crossDomain: true, 
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").html('Connecting...');},
            success: function(json){

            var bigdata = JSON.parse(json);

            var row = '';
            $.each(JSON.parse(json), function(i, d) {

                $.each(d, function(j, e) {

                    if(j == 'gallery_image') {

                    row+='<a href="http://192.168.0.104/upload/gallery/'+e+'" rel="gallery-1" class="swipebox col-33" title="My Caption"> <img src="http://192.168.0.104/upload/gallery/'+e+'" alt="image" class="col-100"> </a>';

                    }  

                });


            });  

            $('#gallery1').append(row);


            }

            });


 $('.swipebox' ).swipebox();

});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to put `$('.swipebox' ).swipebox();` at end of  ajax success ?

Comment: OMG thanks !!!Its working Now!!!

Comment: You are welcome, accept my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swipebox is being fired before added content.

Put

```
$('.swipebox' ).swipebox();
```

at end of ajax success, since you are adding dynamic content.